# dyploying javafx on web

Tags: browser, deployment, web, embed, javafx

I want to build set of tools for my team and they will be as part of JavaFX application for which GUI will be build with help of SCENE BUILDER. I have seen everything that was available but I need an example how to embed this type of application on the server from which it can be invoked somehow. Please help with examples and links. I'd like to make it look as this one. http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Place a copy of the jar, jnlp and html file output by the NetBeans JavaFX project build or [JavaFX packaging tools deploy command](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) into a directory of your webserver, then access the html file in your browser.

For example, let's say you called your application MyPowerApp and netbeans output MyPowerApp.html and you wanted to deploy that to a local Tomcat server:

1. Download and install a [copy of Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi)
2. Copy the jar, jnlp and html file into tomcat's webapps/ROOT directory.
3. Start tomcat.
4. Access your application via `http://localhost:8080/MyPowerApp.html`
   The applet will start automatically and you can click on the link to launch the application via WebStart.

To update the application just rebuild it in NetBeans, copy it over into the tomcat webapps/ROOT directory and refresh your browser link (no need to restart Tomcat).

In practice you will want to modify the html rather than use the generated html to embed either the applet or WebStart link somewhere on your website (you won't need both execution modes in a single page like the Netbeans generated sample).

You may need to [sign your application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH) if it refers to needs permissions outside of the jnlp application sandbox.

To get the application to fill a browser window like Ensemble, it's height and width need to be set to 100% and the HTML page template modified to not have any page margins (view source on the Ensemble page for a sample).

You can include your fxml in your application jar and load it from there or you can load it off your server relative to your application deployment directory.

The information above is a variation of my forum answer [on deploying JavaFX web applications to a server](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH).

See the JavaFX deployment guide and Ensemble sample application source for more info.

- [deployment guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm)
- [deployment QuickStart](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/basic_deployment.htm)
- [ensemble sample application](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html)
- [JavaFX sample application source at the JavaFX demos and samples link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: i tray to put jar and html page and jnlp on real web project that run in wildfly server, it doesn't make a sense. It work only out from server.

Comment: @kamel, if you would like assistance, you should ask a question (with enough detail that it would be possible for somebody to replicate your issue and solve it).

Comment: okay, I asked a question short time before, some one  told that my question is duplicated. I then I removed it.

Comment: I understand kamel, sometimes StackOverflow isn't the best venue to get assistance.  You could try asking on the [JavaRanch JavaFX forums](http://www.coderanch.com/forums/f-98/JavaFX) or [Oracle JavaFX forums](https://community.oracle.com/community/java/java_desktop/javafx_2.0_and_later), though those sites only get a small percentage of traffic compared to a site like StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks jewelsea, So hopeful.